# Averaging using Group by and Distinct in sql

Tags: group-by, ssms, distinct, average

This is a bit convoluted but I will try to make it not so. Below is a snippet of the data and the intended result below it. For every combination of state, area, indcode, and ownership I want to calculate an average. My knowledge of AVG in SQL would average the entire column not just specific values.

```
state   areatype   area   period   indcode   ownership    sites   employment
 32        05     000001     01    102800        12          25         256
 32        05     000001     01    102900        13           6          26
 32        05     000003     01    102800        12         774        1874
  .
  .   
 32        05     000001     02    102800        12          27         239
 32        05     000001     03    102800        12          28         241
 32        05     000001     04    102800        12          29         248
```

Intended result

```
 32        05     000001     00    102800        12          27         246
```

Would the following code do this or be even close?

```
Select avg(employment, sites)
From Select (Distinct(state, area, indcode, ownership) from dbo.tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select
 [state], areatype, area, '00' [period], indcode, ownership, 
 avg(sites) sites, avg(employment) employment
 from dbo.tablename
 group by [state], areatype, area, indcode, ownership;
```

Got this mostly by trial and error and help from another site. Not really sure why it works but its close enough.